# openmp task final

Tags: task, openmp, final

I have a little problem regarding the final clause of the task concept.
The following code is working fine with the if-else statement which ensures that tasking is aborted at a length of less than 100 elements of an recursive quicksort implementation.
Now I want to implement this with the final clause but I doesn't work. It is much slower than with the if-else statement

```
//if ( length > 100 ){
   #pragma omp task untied final(length < 100) mergeable
   do_something(a,c);
   #pragma omp task untied final(length < 100) mergeable
   do_something(b,c);
//}else{
//      do_something(a,c);
//      do_something(b,c);
//}
```

Comment: Your question speaks some about your doubt. But it's not clear enough. Can you please post both your original code and your new code? Also, is `do_something` a recursive call here? It's not clear. By the way, when you reply, make sure you add `@Haozhun`. Otherwise I won't be notified.

Comment: You might want to replace the `final` clause with an `if` clause: `if(length > 100)`.

Comment: Sorry, I really don't get your answer... maybe an edit to the question would have been more appropriate in this case?